# How are workplace problems different to HR problems?

Tags: discussion, scope

From [What topics can I ask about here? - Help Center - The Workplace Stack Exchange](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> The Workplace Stack Exchange is a Q&A site about the workplace and other career-related topics. With your help we're working to build a library to every question about the workplace related to:
>
> - Finding employment (resumes/cv/cover letters, recruiters, hiring-managers, interviews, negotiations, etc.)
> - Maintaining employment (promotions, pay increases, harassment, bullying, poor working conditions, communication problems, etc.)
> - Leadership in the workplace (motivating people, encouraging people, making decisions, holding hard conversations, intervening in unproductive situations, asking for and giving help, etc.)
> - Terminating employment (notice period, breaking the news, handing over work, reference letters, relieving letters, etc.)

I don't have much experience in workplace. Are they all HR problems? Can you give an example when a workplace problem isn't a HR problem and vice versa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are they all HR problems? Can you give an example when a workplace problem isn't a HR problem and vice versa?

Some companies don't even have an HR Dept. Sometimes "HR is your boss" (as in there is no HR department, your boss just fills such roles as well)...

As example, say, having a communication problem with a coworker and asking us help in phrasing certain request is a workplace problem and not an HR one (HR has nothing to do here, just some OP having difficulty finding the right words).

Thus, not all workplace problems are HR problems.

Some Junior Assistant to HR Chief not finding the shared folder where they keep the Employee's info that they were asked to update is a HR problem, but not something one could ask on TWP. The same Junior HR Assistant not knowing some formula for calculating payment based on hours worked is an HR problem, but more of a knowledge/ignorance problem

However, these examples may be a bit of a stretch, and after some analysis we *could* say that perhaps many (all?) HR problems are also workplace problems (as, intrinsically, HR function for/with the company).

Answer (score 1):

Interviewing issues aren't usually HR problems. Nor are conflict resolutions in many situations.

If you go through the questions on the site, very few of them are HR issues I would think.

The HR perspective is often NOT the best solution for individuals. What we do here is to give solutions that work best for the individual rather than the company.

Comment: What kinds of interviewing issues or conflict resolutions aren't HR problem?

Comment: Most of them.... and sometimes the HR dept is the problem someone needs to solve